# Can I package an appxbundle file as msi format?

Tags: uwp, windows-installer, appx

I have created an UWP app package with a appxbundle file and I want to know can I package it as MSI format? how can I make it work?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05792cba-66e9-4e5f-ba01-7cb345fed24c/uwp-how-to-convert-msi-file-for-windows-10-uwp-apps?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: with the latest sdk you can even distribute your apps as msix ( combination of appx and msi ) : https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/08/09/microsoft-msix-replacing-msi-appx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be achievable with Advanced Installer. You can try to import your [.APPX file into a setup project](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-import-appx.html) and then [add an MSI build type](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-multiple-builds.html#create-new-build) to the setup project.